# How would I use an ANY condition to filter if any rows of a group have a 0 value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have this dataframe...

```
var df = Seq(("Steve",1),("Steve",0),("Michael",3),("Michael",2),("Katherine",4),("Katherine",0),("Devin",0),("Devin",0)).toDF("name","score")
```

[image]

I want to return the unique names where NONE of their scores are equals to zero. So in this case, the only name that would be returned would be Michael, since both of his scores above zero.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want a condition to apply on several rows, you need to use either [groupBy](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-groupby-on-dataframe/) or [Window](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/) functions

In your case, you can group by column "name", aggregate the list of scores for each name and then filter out all the records where list of score contains 0. Your code would be:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_set, array_contains, not}

df.groupBy("name")
  .agg(collect_set(col("score")).as("all_scores"))
  .filter(not(array_contains(col("all_scores"), 0)))
  .select("name")
```